# Dereferencing and Referencing Class Example

Tags: c++, c

I have two variables: x and x_ptr

Let's say I initially have the following:

```
Addr    Data    Variable

0x300    7      x
0x104           x_ptr
```

What will the following yield: `*x_ptr = &x;` ?

From my understanding, the reference operator `&` gives the address of the variable following the operator; the dereference operator `*` gives the value at the memory location stored in the variable following the operator.

Therefore, `&x` should give 0x300 and `*x_ptr` should give the value stored at memory location 0x300, which is `int 7`.

So I expect `*x_ptr = &x;` to store the memory address of x into the memory location stored in x_ptr.

But because x_ptr initially has no value stored, it should yield an error, no?

But my class notes say this is the expected result:

```
Addr    Data    Variable

0x300    7      x
0x104    0x300  x_ptr
```

I don't see why this occurs. 
If we want x_ptr to store the memory address of x, shouldn't we write:

`x_ptr = &x` instead?

I've looked through multiple stackexchange answers, but I don't see where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `x` has the type `int` and `x_ptr` has the type `int*`, then the expression `*x_ptr = &x` is invalid.  The type of `*x_ptr` is `int`, and the type of `&x` is `int`.  Those types do not match, so the assignment is not valid.

The expression `x_ptr = &x` is valid.  It sets the value of `x_ptr` to the address of `x`.

Answer (score 1):

You are right.

`*x_ptr = &x` is only valid if the type of `x_ptr` is `int **`. This will make the type of `*x_ptr` an `int *`.

Given these types, `*x_ptr = &x` will write the address of `x` into the address stored in `x_ptr`.

If the memory is:

```
Addr    Data    Variable

0x300    7      x
0x104    0x011  x_ptr
```

Then with `*x_ptr = &x` `0x300` should go into the memory location `0x011`. If x_ptr is not initialized memory `0x104` will not be empty but will be garbage and the assignment will result in undefined behavior and most probably crash the code.

Answer (score 0):

At first **indexes=pointers** are just like any other varieble

**int *x_ptr, x=7;**//but they are still different like float and int

**x=7;** //meaning &x=7 the name x refers directly to a variable which is equal to 7
{like x(7)}

**x_ptr->x=7** the pointer-> refers inexactly to a variable x which value equals to 7
{x_ptr->{x}7}

**The "inexactly" is called indirection**

*** & act like the key and the lock**

**In conclusion**:*xptr **points** at **x** its your choice to be memory or its value

---

Hope i helped u :)